# "Know who is that person" vs "know who that person is"

Tags: word-order, inversion, reported-speech

Is it:

> I would like to know **who is that person** he is speaking to.

or:

> I would like to know **who that person** he is speaking to **is**.

I am confused as to which sentence structure is grammatically accurate. Or are both sentences correct?

Comment: The first one is wrong since it exhibits subject-auxiliary inversion, which subordinate interrogative clauses (aka embedded questions) do not normally have. The meaning is "I would like to know the answer to the question 'Who is that person he is speaking to?'"

Comment: @BillJ But such sentences are grammatical for some speakers - at least according to CamGEL ...